# why is ivars needed in Cocoa when they aren't needed in iOS?

Tags: cocoa, ios, properties

I kind of like the iOS way of not having to specify ivars, but I dunno wether it's possible to do the same in Cocoa or if it's a bad idea.

---

Here is the same code in Cocoa and iOS

```
// Cocoa
@interface Foobar : NSObject {
    NSString* m_name;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@end

@implementation Foobar
@synthesize name = m_name;
@end
```

---

```
// iOS
@interface Foobar : NSObject {
    // no ivar here
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@end

@implementation Foobar
@synthesize name;
@end
```

---

Comment: I've always specified ivars in my iOS code.

Comment: I have also done that, but my iOS friend pointed out that it wasn't necessary. Which puzzles me.

Comment: You can also omit the instance-variables section (`{…}`) from the `@interface` entirely, and when you include it, you can have it in `@implementation` instead of `@interface`. My coding style ever since I discovered this is to only put the instance-variables section in `@implementation`, if at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ability to elide ivars requires the “non-fragile” Objective-C runtime. 32-bit versions of Mac OS X use the “fragile” runtime. If you’re targeting 64-bit systems only, you can do it the same way is on iOS.

Comment: Aha, after reading up on "fragile" I finally get it. Thank you. http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html